# haskell parallel programming

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
import Data.List

genkstrings :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
genkstrings k [] = []
genkstrings 1 (s:ss) = [ [c] | c <- s ] ++ genkstrings 1 ss
genkstrings k (s:ss)
  | length (s:ss) < k = []
  | otherwise = concat [kStartWith k c ss | c <- s ]
                ++
                genkstrings k ss

kStartWith k c ss =
 map (c :) $ genkstringsNogap (k-1) ss

genkstringsNogap 0 _ = []
genkstringsNogap 1 (s:ss) = [ [c] | c <- s ]
genkstringsNogap k (s:ss) = concat $ [kStartWithNoGap k c ss | c <- s ]

kStartWithNoGap k c ss = map (c:) (genkstringsNogap (k-1) ss)
```

Input: `genkstrings 2 ["sds","ghghg"]`

Output:

```
["sg","sh","sg","sh","sg","dg","dh","dg","dh","dg","sg","sh","sg","sh","sg"]
```

I am learning Haskell and I found I can run my code paralleled. I found some examples in the books that I am reading but I don't understand how can I apply Parallel programming it.

if I am correct I should apply it on this line

```
| otherwise = concat [kStartWith k c ss | c <- s ]
                    ++
                    genkstrings k ss
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I doubt you can win much by parallelizing this function. There's not much of interesting computation here, performance is very much bound by the cache-performance of all those lists. Switch at least to [`Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) or [`Bytestring`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) before considering any more special optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post now. There're many ways to make a parallel computing.

You could read this three libraries:

[Control.Parallel](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.1/docs/Control-Parallel.html)

[Control.Parallel.Strategies](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.1/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html)

[Control.Monad.Par](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-par-0.3.4.8/docs/Control-Monad-Par.html) (for monads)

Then, I use to use two ways:

```
right `par` 
left `pseq` 
left ++ right
```

and

```
result `using` strategy
  where
    result = losort ++ (x:hisort)
    losort = quicksortP1 [y|y <- xs, y < x]
    hisort = quicksortP1 [y|y <- xs, y >= x]
    strategy = parList rseq
```

here some results:

```
-- parList rpar     -- 2m42s N=4
-- parList rseq     -- 38.3s N=4
-- parList r0       -- 57.3s N=4
-- parList rdeepseq -- 2m40s N=4
-- r0               -- 48.5s N=4
```

and if you want to get deep :)

```
    result = losort ++ (x:hisort)
    (losort,hisort) = 
      ( quicksortP2 [y|y <- xs, y < x]
      , quicksortP2 [y|y <- xs, y >= x]
      ) `using` strategy 
    strategy = 
            parTuple2 rdeepseq rdeepseq -- 17.9s N=4
--             parTuple2 rdeepseq rseq  -- 18.0s N=4            
--             parTuple2 rdeepseq r0    -- 42s N=4 
--             parTuple2 rseq     rseq  -- 23.8s N=4
--             parTuple2 rpar     rpar  -- 26.9s N=4
--             parTuple2 r0       r0    -- 47.6s N=4
--             r0                       -- 46.2s N=4
```

where `N` is the number of processors I used.

So, knowing it, you could easily adapt it.

And for compiling:

```
> ghc MyProg.hs -threaded -rtsopts
> ./MyProg +RTS -N4 -s
```

I hope I can help someone.